# Deployer Finalize - not finalizing

Tags: web8.5, deployer, deployer-conf

During a publish cycle one of my data-centres is eventually failing transactions indicating they are not deployed.

Publishing a couple of hundred items is OK. When I push in a few hundred (I want around 200 thousand eventually!) then the success stops to increment and all transactions stop in `waiting for deployment` until they eventually timeout.

**Finer details**:

- I'm using the `MIRROR` strategy in deployment.
- Mirror_1 is a simple master and single worker
- Mirror_2 is an AWS Load-balancer endpoint
- The AWS load balancer points to two masters, with two workers

Now - and this may be very related: I did have to move a `Finalize="true"` from the deployer config as I had the error noted below:

[image]

This strikes me as very odd given the XSD would appear to support it:

[image]

**QUESTION**:
Why can I not include the `Finalize="true"` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSD was updated where the second complexType above (PipelinesType) was actually PipelineType which conflicted from the first.

We have no record of it being updated but it was. Having changed it (or re-copied the install version over it) and restarting the services we thought it would have been up to speed.

Seems a Linux reboot did the trick!